# I don't get all my string back after a split and a join

Tags: python

I'm working on an exercise where I have a `sentence` and a `word` given in argument. I have to replace the `word` in the sentence by `*`. So for this I did this:

```
def censor(text, word):
    x = text.split()
    for i in x:
        x = i.replace(word, "*" * len(word))
        print(x)
    x = " ".join(x)
    print(x)


censor("Hi mister toto", "toto")
```

So when I print out my string in the loop area, It's sorting like that:

```
Hi
mister
****
```

But then when I `join` the string back, it just display the last word of the string.
What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Just don't use the variable name `x` inside your loop.

Comment: If I don't use `x`, the `replace` doesn't apply to it, it print the basic sentence.

Comment: @schwobaseggl but the "init" x would not be replaced. I propose declare new empty string and concatenate each loop after replace

Comment: if you are going to use a replace, why do the split at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, your x variable is only the last value on iteration

```
def censor(text, word):
    x = text.split()
    s = []
    for i in x:
        x = i.replace(word, "*" * len(word))
        print(x)
        s.append(x)
    print(" ".join(s))
```

OUTPUT

```
Hi mister ****
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that you use `x` both for the result of the censoring as well as the list of words.

```
def censor(text, word):
    return " ".join(
        "*" * len(w) if word == w else w for w in text.split()
    )

print(censor("Hi mister toto", "toto"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you set the list x to the current word i with x = i.replace(...). So after the last iteration, x is just the string "****".

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I used python so I might be wrong, but it looks like you overwrite x with i. Try using more variables like this:

```
def censor(text, word):
    x = text.split()
    newText = ""
    for i in x:
        censoredWord = i.replace(word, "*" * len(word))
        print(censoredWord)
        newText += censoredWord + " "
    print(newText)



censor("Hi mister toto", "toto")
```

Generally it helps to use clearer variables names to catch yourself making these mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` variable is originally the list of words in the text, but inside the for loop you do `x = i.replace(word, "*" * len(word))`. This reassigns `x` to be the censored word, e.g. "****". Then, when you do `" ".join(s)` at the end, Python joins *every character* in the censored word string with a space, so you get "* * * *". This is because strings in Python can be iterated across with a for loop, just like lists can:

```
for character in "abcd":
    print(character)

# This prints:
# a
# b
# c
# d
```

You can avoid this problem by assigning your replacements back to the list inside the for loop.

```
def censor(text, censored_word):
    words = text.split()
    replacement = "*" * len(censored_word)
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        words[i] = word.replace(censored_word, replacement)
        print(words[i])
    censored_text = " ".join(words)
    print(censored_text)


censor("Hi mister toto", "toto")

# This prints:
# Hi
# mister
# ****
# Hi mister ****
```

However, a simpler solution is to avoid the for loop altogether by using [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) directly on the input text.

```
def censor(text, word):
    replacement = "*" * len(word)
    return text.replace(word, replacement)


print(censor("Hi mister toto", "toto"))  # Prints "Hi mister ****"
```